# Modify behaviour of subobjects

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

Is there any way to modify the behaviour (methods) of a sub-object by redefining  them when subclassing a component . e.g I am subclassing Tlistbox , and i want to modify the behaviour of Delete() method of its Items subobject . Is there a formal way to do so ?
Thanks

Comment: Delphi XE introduced a [`TVirtualMethodInterceptor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TVirtualMethodInterceptor) class that can do what you are asking for, since `Delete()` is virtual, but nothing like that exists in Delphi 7 (unless you back port it manually), and you don't have direct access to replace the `Items` object with a different implementation. What are you really trying to accomplish? There might be a different way to handle it.

Comment: I am adding extra internal info structure attached to the items property , so I want either to add it to the objects[] list, and in this case I have to restrict the use of items.add () to prevent entering the a string without the new info, or make a separate tstrings object and redefine items.add and items.delete to synchronize the two tstrings objects.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, you don't actually need to change the behavior of the `Items` property itself.  There are other ways to detect when items are being manipulated in the ListBox so you can update your own internal objects as needed.

When deleting items, the `Items.Delete()` method simply calls `TCustomListBox.DeleteString()` passing it the index to delete.  `DeleteString()` can be overridden by a descendant.  Simple enough.

When adding/inserting new items, it is not quite so straight forward.  `Items.Add()` sends a `LB_ADDSTRING` message directly to the ListBox's `HWND` (unless the ListBox's `Style` is set to virtual mode, in which case `Add()` simply exits without doing anything).  Same with the `Items.Insert()` method (`LB_INSERTSTRING` message).  To catch those message, you have to override the ListBox's virtual `WndProc()` method.

`Items.AddObject()` calls `Items.Add()` first, and then uses the `Items.Objects[]` setter to assign the object to the new item.  Same with `Items.InsertObject()`, calling `Items.Insert()` instead of `Items.Add()`.

When updating an existing item's string via the `Items.Strings[]` property, things get a bit complex:

1. `TCustomListBox.InternalGetItemData()` (can be overridden) is called to retrieve the item's existing object, if any.  By default, `InternalGetItemData()` calls `GetItemData()` (which can also be overridden), which by default sends a `LB_GETITEMDATA` message to the ListBox's `HWND`.
2. `TCustomListBox.InternalSetItemData()` (which can be overridden) is called to set the item's object to nil (in case `Delete()` in the next step tries to destroy it).  By default, `InternalSetItemData()` calls `SetItemData()` (which can also be overridden), which by default sends a `LB_SETITEMDATA` message to the ListBox's `HWND`.
3. `Items.Delete()` is called to remove the item.
4. `Items.InsertObject()` is called to insert the new string with a `nil` object
5. `TCustomListBox.InternalSetItemData()` is called to restore the original object to the new item.

When updating an existing item's object via the `Items.Objects[]` property, if the ListBox's `Style` is not set to virtual mode then `TCustomListBox.SetItemData()` is called.

When moving items around using the `Items.Exchange()` method, if the ListBox's `Style` is set to virtual mode then `Exchange()` simply exits without doing anything. Otherwise, it uses the `Items.Strings[]` property to swap the two item strings, and calls `Internal(Get/Set)ItemData()` to swap the two item objects.

So, basically, everything you need to manage internal objects boils down to overriding these methods:

1. `TCustomListBox.DeleteString()`
2. `TCustomListBox.WndProc()` to handle `LB_(ADD/INSERT)STRING`, and maybe `LB_(GET/SET)ITEMDATA`.
3. `TCustomListBox.Internal(Get/Set)ItemData()` or `TCustomListBox.(Get/Set)ItemData()`